# Kivy : how to add a button to a dictionary?

Tags: python, kivy

**EDIT for clarity:**

I want to generate N number of buttons with a for loop and add them to an existing widget.

I want to add each button to a dictionary and give it a random value of 0 or 1. When I click on a button, a message will print depending if the button has a value of 0 or 1.

So far this is what I have come up with (in this case, let's say I want to create 10 buttons):

```
self.dict = {}

for n in range(10):
    self.dict.update({Button(text='text':random.randint(0,1)})
    self.add_widget({Button(text='text':random.randint(0,1)})
```

In the end I do have 10 buttons in the graphic interface. However, I cannot reference the buttons, when I print the dictionary I get values such as these:

```
{<kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x11951d7b0>: '1', <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x11953ed60>: '1', <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x119556d60>: '0'}
```

Is there any way to reference buttons (that were generated in a `for loop`) in a dictionary ?

Comment: Try creating a single instance of `Button` for both purpose.

Comment: You mean manually creating `button1`, `button2`, etc ? They need to be generated in a for loop.

Comment: It's hard to guess the actual context seeing only this amount of code. Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just edited the post, it should be clearer now.